# For Loop Iteration Solution

Tags: c#, for-loop, iteration, stack-overflow

I have a basic grasp of For Loops in C#, but I'm having difficulty following this particular function. I have attempted to run the function in Visual Studio, but it results in an overflow exception.

"Describe what will happen when you call doSomething(5) given the following function:"

```
private void doSomething(int x = 10)
{
for(var y = 1; y <= x; y++)
{
Console.WriteLine(y);
if(y == 3)
doSomething(x);
}
}
```

Here's what I can see from analyzing the code. Starting from 1 the loop will check if y is <= 10. If y <= 10, it will write the value of y to the console. It will then check to see if y is equal to 3. If true, it will then call doSomething again, checking y against 10 again.

Comment: If you can run the program, I am pretty sure you can put a break point and observe the flow clearly

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are looking for. Question seem to be "Describe what will happen when you call doSomething(5) given the following function:" and post already contains answer "results in an overflow exception."

Comment: "Describe what will happen" -> "it results in an overflow exception" You've described what happened, so what's the problem?

Comment: Hmm... even more confusing with new edit that explains what happens... Please post answer as answer (self answers are ok), don't edit your question with it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and pointing out that I already had my answer. I assumed I wasn't constructing the code correctly in Visual studio, but I should have trusted myself as well as Visual Studio that the code was correct, but an intentional infinite loop.

Comment: Whenever you describe an exception to someone, be certain to give the full exception information. For instance, there's no such thing as an "overflow exception". There is StackOverflowException and I believe there is OverflowException. Which one are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

It is a recursive function, if you call doSomethig (5), when it enters the cycle will send to doSomethig the same value (in this case 5) forever.

Answer (score 0):

If you create simulation how this code will assign values to variables, you will notice that y will always be assigned with 3, that means doSomething(x) will be called infinity times and calling something infinity times results to overflow exception.